# Accessing inherited class in a derived object

Tags: c++

I have a base class that is inherited into a derived class.  I then instantiate both base and derived objects.

```
class Base
    { public : 
            Base() {} 
         ~Base) {}  };

class Derived : public Base
    { public : 
            Derived() {} 
         ~Derived() {}  };

Base b;
Derived d;
Derived::Base::d = b;
```

Now I'd like to copy the base class object (b) into the derived class object (d) in place of it's inherited base class.  Any ideas on the syntax?

Comment: Anything accepting a base with accept a derived, if base is copyable 'Base b = d;' should work.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: *"Any ideas on the syntax?"* - That's not a question on a specific problem. Stackoverflow is about specific problems with specific solutions.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're trying to say is that you want to initialize the data members of a `Derived` to those members from some `Base`.

You can do this with a copy constructor in `Base`, and a corresponding constructor in `Derived` that passes the value on.

[Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80b79db222d2e4b6):

```
class Base
{ 
    public : 
        Base() { /*...*/}
        Base(const Base& other){/*...*/}
        virtual ~Base() {/*...*/}  
    private:
        /*...*/
};

class Derived : public Base
{ 
    public : 
        Derived() {/*...*/} 
        ~Derived() {/*...*/} 
        Derived(const Base& other) : Base(other){/*...*/}

};

int main()
{
    Base b;
    Derived d(b);
}
```

You can do similar operations for forwarding constructors and assignment operators.

Comment: Good job making the base classes destructor virtual which is important!

Comment: @user3282085: Only if the classes are going to be used polymorphically. If not, then adding a virtual destructor is a waste.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Derived::Base::d = b;
> ```
>
> Any ideas on the syntax?

It's wrong. Options for a working syntax would include:

- `static_cast<Base&>(d) = b;`
- `d.Base::operator=(b1);`

Both are pretty ugly; a result of the fact that the assignment operator in the subclass hides the base version. As is often the case in C++, the ugliness of the syntax indicates that this kind of operation is unusual and that refactoring may be a good idea.

---

Generally, operator overloading and inheritance don't mix well, especially if you are using inheritance for object-oriented programming (i.e. with virtual functions). In that case, one typically makes sure that the class is not assignable at all (which C++11 makes very easy because you simply `delete` the generated assignment operator in the base class).

You should also read more about object slicing, for example all answers and comments for these two questions:

- [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)
- [C++ slicing causing leak / undefined behavior / crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606143/c-slicing-causing-leak-undefined-behavior-crash)